# .bat - how to remove "dot" and "dot dot" items from dir command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a batch to run a command on all directories in current directory.

To start, I do `dir /A:D` but that gives even the `.` and `..` directories on which I do NOT want to run my command.

I know I can exclude them by writing

```
IF NOT %%x EQU "."
    IF NOT %%x EQU ".."
```

But is there more generic way? Like:

```
set EXCLUDED=".","..","bob"
set FOLDERS=dir /A:D
rem for each in EXCLUDED, remove from FOLDERS
rem run my command(s) on FOLDERS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `/b` switch to exclude `.` and `..`, as long as you don't need the other information given by `dir /a:d`.

To exclude other directories, use `find /v` like this:

```
dir /a:d /b | find /v "bob" | find /v "alice"
```

The `/v` switch will output everything else but the given line.

Comment: Is there a solution where, like my question, you can provide a VAR that contains a list of items to exclude? That'd be the most generic solution.

Comment: @Adrian You could use `findstr /v` to act on lines not matching a regexp, and set a variable to the regexp you want to exclude.  `findstr` syntax treats spaces as delimiters for multiple search terms.  For example, `set "excluded=intel links logitech"` then `dir /b /a:d | findstr /i /v "%excluded%"` would match all directories excluding Intel, Links, or Logitech (case-insensitive).  Or if the action you intend to take can be handled by `robocopy`, you could use `robocopy`'s `/XD` switch to exclude directories you specify.  Or if `xcopy`, you could use its `/exclude` switch.

Comment: @rojo ok sounds like what I want. I'll accept your answer once I edit it and paste the stuff that you wrote in the comment section.

Comment: This is the command line to eliminate spaces:
`dir /A:D | findstr /V /E /L ".." | findstr /V /E /L "."`

Unforunately, `findstr` doesn't support full regex so:
`/V` is to remove lines matching `.`
`/E` is to match at END of line (since `.` and `..` are at end)
`/L` is to match the literal `..` and `.`

You *could* combine it into one expression
`dir /A:D | findstr /V /E /R "\.\. \."` but that only works if your two patterns have no spaces since [spaces are used as delimiters when combining two regex](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you use a `for` loop (probably `for /f "..." %%x in ('dir ...') do ...`). There is a special parameter `/D` to work with directories:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%x IN (*) do (
  ECHO %%x|FINDSTR /ivx "bob joe jane">nul && (
    ECHO do stuff with %%x
  ) || (
    ECHO skipping %%x
  )
)
```

(works, as long as there are no spaces in the "to exclude" folder names)

PS: no need to exclude `.` and `..` here, because `for /d` doesn't show them.